# Adding value of cell X only if cell Y is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list with three columns A, B, and C. The first two columns are complete (A and B), while the third (C) has many blanked fields.

What I want to do is replace all the blank fields in Column C with the same value form cell A in the same row.

The List contains over 2000 records, of which 65% have a blank Column C value, so I would like to use a formula/function.

Below is an example of what I have and what I want to do (on a much smaller scale)

[image]

Comment: What about this: =IF(TRIM(C1) <> "", C1, A1)

Comment: Both have resulted in a value of 0 so far

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this trick to fill in the blank cells in Column `C`.

1. Select Column `C` in your table (e.g. `C1:C2000`).
2. Press <kbd>F5</kbd>. Click the 'Special...' button.
3. Choose 'Blanks' and click 'OK'.
4. Type `=A2` (I'm assuming the first blank is in row 2, as in your example. It would be `=A3` if the first blank were in row 3, etc.). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That should do the trick.

Comment: That did the trick, although it was easier to just use Sort and Filter, to chose only the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions could be:

1. (only if you need the orginal order) add a temporary column with value from 1 to last before
2. order your dataset by column C (A to Z or Z to A is not important)
3. then tou can easy create two different formulas (D2=A2 if C blanked are up or D2=C2 if C blanked are down)
4. (only if you need the orginal order) reorder the dataset by temporary column created in step 1
5. (only if you need the orginal order) delete the temporary column